# Upload de imagem dentro do repeater C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, file-upload

Olá, sou novo aqui e estou precisando de uma ajuda. Já pesquisei na net e as soluções que encontrei não funcionam.
Tenho uma tela de edição de galeria de imagens, feita com um repeater, em cada imagem listada eu tenho um botão que abre um Ajax modalpopup com um Fileupload. Desta forma posso substituir a foto selecionada.
O problema é que não consigo fazer o upload da foto. Simplesmente não consigo encontrar o arquivo Fileupload no button click no code behind.
Alguém pode me ajudar? Já tentei de tudo e não sei o que estou fazendo de errado.
html:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="card">
                <img src='<%# "../fotosanuncios/" + Eval("idAnuncio") + "/" + Eval("NomeFotoMini") %>'/>
                <div class="containerCard">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LBSubstituir" runat="server" ToolTip="Substituir Foto"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                 <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtenderSub" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" TargetControlID="LBSubstituir" PopupControlID="PanelSubstituir" CancelControlID="BtCancelar" DropShadow="True"></ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
                <asp:Panel ID="PanelSubstituir" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" style="width:400px;">
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" runat="server" CssClass="cg-inputform" /><br />
                    <asp:Button ID="BtCancelar" Text="Cancelar" runat="server" CssClass="cg-inputGrey" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="BtSalvar" Text="Salvar" runat="server" OnClick="BtSalvar_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("idFoto") + "," + Eval("nomeFoto") + "," + Eval("nomeFotoMini") %>' CssClass="cg-inputGreen" />
                </asp:Panel>

                 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonRight" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButtonRight_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("idFoto") + "," + Eval("nomeFoto") + "," + Eval("nomeFotoMini") %>' ToolTip="Girar a Direita"><i class="fa fa-repeat" aria-hidden="true"></i></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonLeft" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButtonLeft_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("idFoto") + "," + Eval("nomeFoto") + "," + Eval("nomeFotoMini") %>' ToolTip="Girar a esquerda"><i class="fa fa-undo" aria-hidden="true"></i></asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

meu codebehind

```
protected void BtSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



              int idAnuncio = Convert.ToInt32(this.Request.QueryString["idAnuncio"]);

                Button BtSalvar = sender as Button;

                string[] commandArgs = BtSalvar.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(new char[] { ',' });
                string idFoto = commandArgs[0];
                string NomeFoto = commandArgs[1];
                string NomeFotoMini = commandArgs[2];


                RepeaterI

tem di = BtSalvar.NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;
            FileUpload fUpload = di.FindControl("FileUpload2") as FileUpload;



            if (fUpload.HasFile)
            {
        //salva a foto

        }          

    }
```

Comment: Desculpe nunca trabalhei com o updatepanel, devo inserir todo o repeater dentro do updatepanel? E porque desta forma ele pega os valores do fileupload? valeu!!

Comment: RepeaterItem di = BtSalvar.NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;

Answer (score 0):

Insira seu código dentro de um UpdatePanel com o atributo  UpdateMode="Conditional", segue abaixo:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upGeral" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
```

No método Page_Load da sua página insira o seguinte código:

```
Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
```

Comment: O meu problema está em como pegar o fileupload. Ele não está passando o arquivo para upload.

Comment: Da uma olhada se isso te ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487984/adressing-a-fileupload-within-a-repeater